# Difference met and had met in english

Tags: sentence-construction, past-perfect, perfect-constructions

> Lalwani, who is much younger to Mallya, had met him when she was hired
>   as a flight attendant for Kingfisher Airlines in 2011.

Is the above sentence construction is correct spcially use of "had met him"?

Can use of simple past like "she met him when" make sense?

Is there any specific rule of using below perfect tense?

> Known and had known
>
> Accompanied and had accompanied

Comment: More time related context (happening at another time) is needed to decide if perfect tenses are appropriate.

Comment: I agree with user3169, we need to know what sentences preceded this in order to decide. past perfect is used to place one event in the past before another event in the past. I don't see that 'another event' here, but it may be in the preceding sentences.

Comment: note that, when comparing two things, we use **than** rather than **to**: it should be "much younger **than"" Mallya".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes and yes.

You could use 'had met him when' or 'met him when' interchangeably in this sentence. The meaning differs only very slightly, as 'had met him' emphasizes that it was in the past, while 'met him' emphasizes the fact of their meeting. It's a very slight difference, though.

The only thing wrong with the sentence is 'who is much younger to Mallya'. "Younger to" is not correct because it's a comparative, and that takes 'than' rather than 'to'. The correct way would be '...much younger than' Mallya.